# Adding ADComputer in a certain OU to a Group by using a GPO

Tags: account, active-directory-group, gpo

OU:BOB,
Group:My-DCs,
GPO:Add-DC-To-Grp

I want to add all computers in Organization Unit "Bob" to Group "My-DCs" with help of the GPO "Add-DC-To-Grp".
Can someone explain how this can be done?

Comment: Have you try to search in the docs?

Comment: Which docs? You mean here on stackoverflow? No I didn't find anything there.